# Nested enums in swift - compering and functions based on enum

Tags: ios, swift, enums

Created a nested enum with  `==` operator and test function for printing:

```swift
enum OperationType{
    case presentController(_ controller: ControllerType)
    enum ControllerType{
        case imagePickerVC, histogramVC, faceDetectionVC, cellDetectionVC,none
    }
    
    case modifyImage(_ modificationType: ModificationType)
    enum ModificationType{
       case saveImage, deleteImage,none
    }
}

extension OperationType: Equatable{
    static func ==(lhs: OperationType,rhs: OperationType)->Bool{
        switch (lhs,rhs) {
        case (.presentController,.presentController):
            return true//lhs_controller == rhs_controller
        case (.modifyImage,.modifyImage):
            return  true//lhs_modificationType == rhs_modificationType
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}

//test func to print
func printX(hs: OperationType){
      switch(hs) {
      case .presentController:
          print("PSC")
          break
      case .modifyImage:
          print("MDI")
          break
      default:
          break
      }
  }
```

When it comes to printing some result ( logic from one ViewController) :

```swift
   let x:OperationType = menuData[indexPath.section].Operations[indexPath.row1].Operation
   let y:OperationType = .modifyImage(.none)
   print("| \(x==y) __ \(printX(hs: x)) |")
```

*It should return something like*

```
| true __ MDI | //or "| false __ PSC |"
```

**But what i get is:**

```
PSC
| false __ () |
```

**OR**

```
MDI
| true __ () |
```

I don't have any clue what's going on here, started learning Swift while ago. Any tips ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printX` doesn't return anything, but it does print to the console. So when you call this:

```
print("| \(x==y) __ \(printX(hs: x)) |")
```

it evaluates `printX(hs: x)` while it is building the string for the print statement. That returns `Void`, which comes out as `()` in the final string, but while doing that, it does write to the console, so you see the value MDI or PSC on the line before.

You can just do `print(x)` and it will give you a reasonable debug description:

```
modifyImage(Untitled.OperationType.ModificationType.none)
```

(Untitled is the module identifier here) or you can make your types implement `CustomDebugStringConvertible` and return something more useful in `debugDescription`.